# ArcPy FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion invalid SQL statement

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, where-clause

I am trying to iterate through a list of where clauses as such:

```
for vc in vcList:
    print (vc)
""""D_Zone" =  1"""
""""D_Zone" =  2"""
""""D_Zone" =  3"""
""""D_Zone" =  4"""
""""D_Zone" =  5"""
```

for each iteration I want to use a for loop to execute aFeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion using the iterable as the where clause:

```
for vc in vcList:
    oName = base + "_" + str(count)
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass('Origins_Geocoded', oPath, oName, vc)
    count += 1
```

but I am getting an invalid SQL error:

```
An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT * FROM Origins_Geocoded WHERE """"D_Zone" =  1"""]
```

The value being queried is short numeric. Seems to be consistent with the first example from Esri:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/specifying-a-query.htm

What must I do to construct a proper where clause?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the clause to only have double quotes around fieldname and sigle quotes to contain the cluse:

```
vcList:
['"D_Zone" = 1', '"D_Zone" = 2', '"D_Zone" = 3', '"D_Zone" = 4', '"D_Zone" = 5', '"D_Zone" = 6']
```